# GET request returns parameter self is unfulfilled

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the code:

```
s = request.Session
s.get(url="http://google.co.uk/")
```

but this returns:

```
    s.get(url="http://google.co.uk/")
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm sure it is an easy fix but I can not seem to find it in the request docs, or in my previous codes as I haven't worked with requests for a while.

Comment: Perhaps `s = request.Session()` to get an instance of a Session class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `request.Session` instead of `requests.Session()`.You can try it:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.get(url="http://google.co.uk/")
```